# Importing a file into local mysql server

Tags: mysql

I am wondering how to take a .sql file and import it into my list of local databases on the same machine. Mose searches I have found instruct me to ssh into a remote server etc.

I want to be able to use:

```
mysql -uroot -p -h localhost databasename < /Downloads/database.sql
```

Comment: And what exactly prevents you from using that command, if we may ask?

Comment: When I type it out that way, it tells me my syntax is incorrect. However, if I am in the same directory as the sql file and do it that way, it doesnt say anything. Im not sure if the sql file is being imported though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice about space:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost databasename < ~/Downloads/database.sql
```

Comment: I think it would work either way